# Any relation between emberjs route and rails route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, routes

One project based on emberjs and rails.

When redirect to  localhost/#lessons/2, the page works

when redirect to  localhost/practices/2#/lessons/2,

## Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

so what's the difference between 'localhost/#lessons/2' and 'localhost/practices/2#/lessons/2'

If want to make  'localhost/practices/2#/lessons/2' works, how to set emberjs route?

Answer (score 1):

> so what's the difference between 'localhost/#lessons/2' and 'localhost/practices/2#/lessons/2'

Difference is the `/practices/2` part. That's part of the url's path. By default ember will ignore that, it's just paying attention to the hash, which in bot cases is `lessons/2`.

Like firefox says, seems like the server is redirecting the request.

> If want to make 'localhost/practices/2#/lessons/2' works, how to set emberjs route?

Hmmm... that url implies that server/rails is responsible for rendering practices/2 and that you have an ember app on the practices/2 page which should be rendering lessons/2? It's possible but that sounds like a very complicated setup. I'd be surprised if that's what you really want. Probably instead you will want to have `localhost/#practices/2/lessons/2`. With that setup just use normal ember routing as described here: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/

Comment: So emberjs app runs under rails root url defautly.

Comment: Kinda. Ember apps don't know about rails. From your question it seems like the html page returned by your rails app's root url contains an ember application, but it would work the same no matter what the rails route and url/path had been. By default ember app does not care what url's path is, instead an ember app's router uses url's hash property. That hash is ignored by the server. If that's not what you want you might use `pushState` instead by setting `location: history`, see:  http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-the-location-api/